# How to collect only selected indexed item's values from dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary contains Line and Dot classes.

Everyline that i found in LineList i add in dictiory 1st item and Dots inside that line to 2nd item.

I want to collect each Dots in one line and repeat it for every other line in dictionary.

```
public void collectingAllLines()
        {
            Dictionary<Line, Dot> TempDotsInLines = new Dictionary<Line, Dot>();

            foreach (Line line in LinesList)
            {
               // Each line contains minimum 2 dots 

                foreach (Dot dot in DotsList)
                {
                    if(line.DotIsOntheLine(dot) == true)
                    {
                        TempDotsInLines.Add(line, dot);
                    }   
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < LinesList.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach(Dot dots in TempDotsInLines[Line[i]])
                {
                    //I am trying to collect all dots in one line from TempDotsInLines dictionary.
                    // I want to turn in all lines in TempDotsInLine dictionary
                    

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to put the same line in dictionary more than once. Dictionary is not what you want to use here.

It would help to see more of your code or have a better understanding of your end goal. But I think you could get what you want by creating a `List<Dot>` public property in your line class. Then you could add matching dots that way to track them.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a collection type as the dictionary class does not support multiple values for the same key.

So you can for example use `Dictionary<Line, List<Dot>>`.

To add dots, you will then need to create a list per line the first time you want to access it:

```cs
if(!TempDotsInLines.TryGetValue(line, out List<Dot> dotList))
   TempDotsInLines[line] = dotList = new List<Dot>();

dotList.Add(dot);
```